# Como calcular el diámetro final teniendo el adyacente y el angulo

Tags: python-3.x

Mi objetivo es que se sume el resultado de h hasta que llegue a 12.5,pero no me funciona.

```
import math
angulo = float(input("Ingrese el ángulo en grados: "))
lado = float(input("Ingrese el lado adyacente: "))
h = lado / math.cos(angulo)
suma = 7
while h <= 12.5:
  print("El valor de h es:", h)
  suma + h
print("La suma de x es igual a 12.5")
```

He intentado varias cosas peor el python lo tengo algo oxidado, así q si alguien es tan amable de ayudarme lo agradecería.
El error creo q es en el

```
suma + h
```

Comment: Pero no estás actualizando `h` o sea nunca va a llegar a ser mayor de 12.5. Prueba con ` h = suma + h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convierte el ángulo ingresado a radianes ya que `math.cos()` espera un ángulo en radianes.

```
h = lado / math.cos(math.radians(angulo))
```

Actualiza el valor de `h` dentro de tu `while` de la siguiente manera:

```
while h <= 12.5:
    print("El valor de h es:", h)
    suma += h  # Sumar h a la variable suma
    h += 1  # Incrementar h
```